# Any way to access the first element after each wrap in a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a dynamic form of sorts that I'm laying out with a css flexbox.  I'm using flex because I don't know until runtime how many or what type/width the components are in the form.  I'd prefer for the first "column" to have left-aligned labels and every subsequent column to have right-aligned ones, but I can't really think of any way to do this.  Any suggestions?

Basic example of this form (with everything right-aligned). Be sure to pull the divider left to make the rendered output as large as possible to see what the form looks like with more than just one column: http://jsfiddle.net/27Gfd/

```
//basic markup for one form component (called a row). See JS fiddle for more
<div class="container">
        <div class="row"> //I might stack next to another "row" because I have fixed width based on component type
            <div class="miniflex"> //I'm another flex container to layout label/input
                <div class="label">Label 1</div>
                <div class="input">
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please provide some CSS and HTML markup so that we can get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Post edited to show example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the moment no, you can't

example **pseudo code** (just an idea, **it doesn't work!**)

```
.flexContainer::first-flex-line > div   {}
.flexContainer::last-flex-line > div    {}
.flexContainer::nth-flex-line(odd)      {}
.flexContainer::nth-flex-line(3n+1)     {}
```

this doesn't exist yet for a precise reason

```
.flexContainer::nth-flex-line(3n+1) > div   {width:100%}
```

changing the size of the flex-items may affect the container's wrapping. so that's a circular loop. not a nice thing! :P

if you can think of a solution and you want it implemented you could ask to the CSSWG using the newsgroup, or even on chrome's and firefox's bug trackers

Answer (score 0):

Change the css:

```
    .ex3 .label{
        text-align: right;
        /* ... */
    }
```

to:

```
    .ex3 .label{
        text-align: left;
        /* ... */
    }
```

Or, if you're not certain that the first column is a label, use:

```
    .miniflex div:first-child {
        text-align: left !important;
    }
```

(You should probably avoid using `!important` but I can't offer a precise alternative without knowing the logic behind the markup.)

Or if you might have labels in places other than the first column

```
    .ex3 .label:first-child {
        text-align: left;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I must not have been clear. I only want the labels left aligned for the first column when the document flow means that you have multiple label/input pairs on the same main axis row.  If you pull the divider in jsfiddle to the left, you'll see the document expand and there'll be > 1 label/input per row.  I updated the question to suggest making the form as big as possible when viewing it to see multiple columns

Comment: Ah, that is an altogether different matter. And it's not possible (AFAIK) to solve with CSS. You could do it with some JavaScript, but I think you'd be better off completely restructuring your markup. The current HTML will give screen readers nightmares.